# ImportError: No module named openpyxl

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, openpyxl

I installed openpyxl via pip3 but whenever I try to import it into my script I get this error:

```
"python -u "/Users/hectorv/zipcodes/zips.py"
hectorv@Hectors-MacBook-Air zipcodes % python -u "/Users/hectorv/zipcodes/zips.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hectorv/zipcodes/zips.py", line 1, in <module>
    import openpyxl
ImportError: No module named openpyxl"
```

When I try to install again I get this:

```
hectorv@Hectors-MacBook-Air zipcodes % pip3 install openpyxl
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

Comment: MacOS ships with `python` calling Python 2, and `python3` calling the system's Python 3.  Do `python -V` to check this.  Does it work if you use `python3 -u zips.py`?  If so, you can make a symbolic link from `~/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: And I just noticed you tagged `vscode`.  Are you running this in a Python extension to vscode?  If so, it might have its OWN Python installation.  If not, you should remove the tag.

Comment: @MikeScotty This is what I got sorry in advance guys I'm a complete noob at programming

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Comment: Do you see that this is 2.7?  You need to type `python3` instead of just `python`.

Comment: python3 -u zips.py worked! but when i try creating the symbolic link "sudo ln -s ~/bin/python /usr/bin/python3" it says that this operation is not permitted

Comment: It's the other way around, and you don't need sudo.  `ln -s /usr/bin/python3 ~/bin/python`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Code Runner`, isn't it?

You can avoid using the `Code Runner`. After you selected the proper python interpreter, you can click the `Run Python File` button, or right-click and select `Run Python File In Terminal` command.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you insist on using the `Code Runner`, you can add `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,` in the settings.json file. This is because if you run the `Code Runner` directly in the `OUTPUT` panel, it will take advantage of the global `python`, ignoring the python interpreter selected by the Python extension.

Comment: yep the code runner extension was the problem thank you!